# How to calculate the difference of two time strings with timezone in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, parsing, datetime, timezone, timedelta

I have two strings

```
s1 = "2013-11-21T07:45:51ZUTC+0000" # Europe
s2 = "2013-11-21T13:15:28ZUTC+0530" # India
```

I like to know the difference in seconds (should be 23 seconds).
I tried:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
dt1 = parse(s1)
dt2 = parse(s2)
(dt1-dt2).total_seconds()
-39577.0
```

This is not the correct result. What do I have to do to get the correct result? TIA!

Comment: The offset is rather.. strangely formatted. As a result, the timezone is parsed in the *wrong* direction. The difference is 11 hours off from your expected value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that your date string will be in the same format. You could help the parse function to figure out the correct date by removing the 'ZUTC' from the string. Like this:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse

s1 = "2013-11-21T07:45:51ZUTC+0000" # Europe
s2 = "2013-11-21T13:15:28ZUTC+0530" # India

def new_parse(string):
    return parse(string.replace('ZUTC', ''))

dt1 = new_parse(s1)
dt2 = new_parse(s2)
print (dt1-dt2).total_seconds()
```

Comment: Yes, the input format is broken; it pretends to use ISO8601 but then uses offsets too (`Z` means UTC). Removing `ZUTC` at least makes it ISO8601 compliant.

Comment: Thanks, this solution works fine! I could even find the culprit code which added the wrong 'Z' and solve this problem in the correct way.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> str(datetime.datetime.strptime("2013-11-21T07:45:51ZUTC+0000", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ%Z%z") - datetime.datetime.strptime("2013-11-21T13:15:28ZUTC+0530", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ%Z%z"))
'0:00:23'
```

Actually 23 seconds.

Comment: Many thanks! Unfortunately, this works with Python 3.2.3, but not with Python 2.7.3. I still need Python 2 and rephrased my question.